# Display dayjs time from when post was created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, dayjs

So I have an express app where you can make posts and such. I want to display how long ago the post was made ie. 5 minutes ago. I have been looking at day.js docs and they say to use:

```
    dayjs(date).fromNow();
```

The problem with this is that it is displaying the time from right now. How can I display the time from when the post was created.

Btw date is stored in my mongodb database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend dayjs with relativeTime. Sample code provided below. Refer [link](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/relative-time)

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs");
const relativeTime = require("dayjs/plugin/relativeTime");
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);

let dateNow = dayjs();
let blogDate = "2020-01-01";
let str = dateNow.from(blogDate, true);
console.log(str); // 9 months
```